# Redirect after submit PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I have a form that calls the classic PHP contact file, that sends the mail. 
Right after the submitting action I want to redirect the user back to the home page.

I tried with:

```
$redirect_page = 'http://example.com';
header ('Location: '.$redirect_page)    ;
```

inside the `contact.php` but it doesn't work.

How can I get it to work?

Comment: is it there any error ?

Comment: no, i just see the blank contact.php page. No errors

Comment: could you please paste code of contact file. so that i can help you futher

Answer (score 0):

A `header()` call must happen before you send any content, including whitespace in your PHP file.

Check for any content that is being sent before you send your headers.

Comment: So you are suggesting to place the header fuunction before my contact.php sends the mail? Will it send the mail anyway doing so?

Comment: Not before contact.php sends the email, but before it writes anything to the browser using `echo` or any similar function, including any content outside of `<?php ?>` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Headers must be sent foremost to the user. Check if their is any echo statement before the PHP Redirection. Or just, change the overall method, and use Javascript Redirection.

```
window.location.assign("URL");
```